# someone spared oneself no something

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Her friends were point out her lavish lifestyle in which **she spared
> herself no earthly pleasure.**

Is it mean she enjoyed pleasure or not?

Comment: Please edit to include the source of the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that she not only enjoyed herself, she enjoy every pleasure she possibly could.

Normally, I have seen it used in the manner "she spared no effort in an attempt to do X" -- that is, everything she could have done, she did.  This means she did not spare -- "to refrain from" or even "to use frugally" -- all her efforts.  "Pleasures" is an unusual usage.